# read hdf5 generated in pandas with matlab (column name)

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, hdf5

I'm trying to read a `hdf5` file generated with Python in MatLab.
The index is a datetime while the content is only numeric.

In earlier answers, I read that one has to use `format='table'`

I managed to get it working, however, I struggle to extract the "column names".

```
# python code:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
idx = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1,1), datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 2))
df = df.set_index(idx)

df.to_hdf('test.h5', 'df', complevel=9, format='table')
df2 = pd.read_hdf('test.h5') # works
```

To read the hdf5 file, I'm using the following code

```
% matlab code
tmp = h5read('test.h5', '/df/table');
val = tmp.values_block_0';
% convert int to datetime:
t0 = datetime(1970,01,01);
idx = tmp.index;
idx = idx * 1e-9;
idx = t0 + seconds(idx);
```

How do I extract the colum names `A` and `B` in Matlab? Can it be done using `h5info` or `h5disp`?
In general, is there a more elegant way to extract the datetime information in MatLab?

Comment: I would recommend downloading [HDFView](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/), which is a tool that allows you browse the internal structure of HDF5 files. With that you should be able to deduce how Python (or whatever) has laid out the HDF5 file and where the `A` and `B` data resides. It should then be a simple matter to craft the relevant `h5read(...)` command in MATLAB.

Comment: HDFView will help "see" the field/column names. Warning: HDF5 files created by Matlab use Object References which can be very tricky to figure out, especially for a new user.